# How to configure IIS to connect to SQL using VPN

Tags: iis, vpn, rdp

Our company has two separate networks. Our local machines are connected to network 1 while our SQL server is located in network 2. Every time we connect to our SQL server, we do a VPN and then do an RDP to SQL server which is in network 2. However, when we run our applications locally in our machines (we are in network 1), even with the VPN on, the application does not run as it can't connect to SQL server.

Is there any settings that needs to be done in IIS so that our application can connect to SQL server via VPN?

Thanks !

Comment: VPN is a network layer setting and you have to enable it at system level. There is no way to enable it only for IIS.

Comment: Can't connect? Exactly what error do you get? Can you ping the host? Can you telnet to the SQL Server port? Can you connect using SQLCMD? If you can RDP but not connect with SQLCMD then it's most likely a firewall / port issue. Do you have a network admin to help?